# Bibliography problem: reference not printed

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I rather new to `bibliography.bib` (bibtex) and I have a weird problem.
My problem is that some items the bib files are printed and some not.
I added part of the main file and part of the bibtex file below. The first bibfile item is printed while the second is not. I have used `\cite{reference name}` for both the items. My question is can some help me with fixing this problem?

```
%%%%Main Tex File%%%%
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{12_Bibliography/bibdatabase}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

%%%% Bibtex File%%%%
@Article{inflatblimp2, %this one is printed
author = {Walkenhorst B.T., Miner G.F., Arnold D.V.},
title = {A low cost, radio controlled blimp as a platform for remote sensing},
journal = {Microwave Earth remote sensing laboratory - Brigham Young University},
year  ={2000},
pages = {}
}

@inbook{TOcost5, %this one is not printed
author = {James R. Wertz, Wiley J. Larson},
title = {Space Mission Analysis And Design},
volume = {8},
edition = {Third}, 
pages = {800-801},
    }
```

Comment: It is good that you showed some latex. Even better, though, would be a working minimal example---a chunk of latex that can be copied into a file as is, and compiles while also exhibiting your issue.

Comment: Isn't `book` a compulsory field for `inbook` in which case, is this the problem?

Comment: I edited the title to make it more specific. If you think it should be changed back you can "roll back" my edit, or you can edit it to make it even more specific if you isolate the problem further.

Answer (score 3):

With `\nocite{*}` both entries are typeset, on my system. Look at the log file produced by BibTeX, which has extension `.blg` for information in case of a missing entry.

By the way, you are specifying author names wrongly:

```
@Article{inflatblimp2,
author = {Walkenhorst, B.T. and Miner, G.F. and Arnold, D.V.},
title = {A low cost, radio controlled blimp as a platform for remote sensing},
journal = {Microwave Earth remote sensing laboratory - Brigham Young University},
year  ={2000},
}

@inbook{TOcost5,
author = {James R. Wertz and Wiley J. Larson},
title = {Space Mission Analysis And Design},
volume = {8},
edition = {Third}, 
pages = {800-801},
}
```

The first entry doesn't look like an article, but more like a techical report.

Comment: Hey guys.

Thanks for all comments and the answer. I managed to fix it. The problem was I had some comment signs (%) in the .bib files and apparently comment signs in a .bib file F'ed everything up. When I deleted all the comments everything was printed :). I hope this will help other people who have the same problem.